# Copy-and-Move Concept Using Smart Pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I tried to implement a simple container class using the copy-and-move idiom. I am learning the changes to C++ as of C++11 and later.

1. Is the code exception safe?
2. I chose to use a smart pointer. Is `std::unique_ptr` a safe choice? I read that it should not be copied, but since I am doing the copying of the content explicitly, and since it provides a swap function, I could not see any objection. Is there a preferred practice, considering the array content type might be any type including an object type?
3. When I let the compiler do the copy for the copy assignment operator (like `...::operator=(MyContainer other)`) I got an ambiguity with the move assignment operator. So I chose to put the copy operation into the function (which I prefer visually, it might look naive and oldschool, but as an aging brain I find it more explicit). Also here: Is there another, preferred practice? And to overcome my personal preference: What is the real difference of letting the compiler do the copy? Both are taking place on the stack, aren't they?

#### Header part

```
class MyContainer
{
private:
    std::size_t mSize;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> mArray;

    static void _swap(MyContainer& first, MyContainer& second);
    void _reset(void);

public:
    MyContainer(std::size_t size); // default constructor
    MyContainer(const MyContainer& other); // copy constructor
    MyContainer(MyContainer&& other) noexcept; // move constructor
    MyContainer& operator=(const MyContainer& other); // copy assignment operator
    MyContainer& operator=(MyContainer&& other) noexcept; // move assignment operator
    void dump(void);
    /* ... */
    ~MyContainer(void);
};
```

#### Source part

```
void MyContainer::_swap(MyContainer& first, MyContainer& second) // static
{
    std::swap(first.mSize, second.mSize);
    first.mArray.swap(second.mArray);
}

void MyContainer::_reset(void)
{
    mSize = 0;
    mArray.reset();
}

MyContainer::MyContainer(std::size_t size = 0) // default constructor
    : mSize(size),
    mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize] : nullptr)
{
    // for testing purpose only
    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
        mArray.get()[i] = i;
}

MyContainer::MyContainer(const MyContainer& other) // copy constructor
    : mSize(other.mSize),
    mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize] : nullptr)
{
    std::copy(other.mArray.get(), other.mArray.get() + mSize, mArray.get());
}

MyContainer::MyContainer(MyContainer&& other) noexcept // move constructor
    : MyContainer() // init using default constructor (C++11)
{
    _swap(*this, other);
}

MyContainer& MyContainer::operator=(const MyContainer& other) // copy assignment
{
    MyContainer tmp(other);
    _swap(*this, tmp);
    return *this;
}

MyContainer& MyContainer::operator=(MyContainer&& other) noexcept // move assignment
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        _reset();
        _swap(*this, other);
    }
    return *this;
}


void MyContainer::dump(void)
{
    std::cout << "Size: " << mSize << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
        std::cout << mArray.get()[i] << std::endl;
}

MyContainer::~MyContainer(void)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`unique_ptr` is fine here. It's used where you would have used a plain pointer before.

But don't use naked `new` — use make_unique.  Oh, and I think a unique_ptr of array types was not in C++11 but needs C++14.

Don’t use (void) for () in parameter lists!  That was *never* proper, even in c++98. (it was supported to allow compatibility with C headers, but in Bjarne’s own words it’s “an abomination”.

Don’t write an empty destructor.  Use =default to emphasize that it exists, or just leave it off completely.

Why have a private `_swap` static function instead of a non-member overload of `swap` that anyone can use?

Another important new feature you have not embraced yet is the range `for` loop.  Use that instead of the lagacy `for` loops you have that go over the whole array.

Comment: In addition to your point about the `swap` function it's also worth noting that [leading underscores are UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @yuri - that's a good point, **if** the swap function is moved to the global namespace.  It's allowed (but ugly) in class scope.

Comment: In the general case, `~() = default` sometimes does more than advertise that objects can be destructed - it can sometimes prevent types being "trivial", which can affect performance.  Good practice is not to declare it unless you need to, and `= default` only when you need to make it virtual (or the default needs to destruct a type that's not complete in the header file, e.g. with a unique pointer to pimpl).

Comment: “The destructor for class T is trivial if all of the following is true:
    The destructor is not user-provided (meaning, it is either implicitly declared, or **explicitly defined as defaulted** on its first declaration) ”

Answer (score 3):

### Your specific questions

Yes, I'd say that `unique_ptr` is exactly right.  The only place we use `new`, there's no window for any exception to leak the memory.  The destructor cleans up for us, and we never use the pointed-to memory after it's gone.

Well done on a robust implementation!

Consider the following to be polishing, rather than ripping up your code.

### Missing headers

The header file needs

```
#include <cstddef>              // size_t
#include <memory>               // unique_ptr
```

And the implementation needs:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
```

### Default constructor

The default argument should be supplied in the header, not the implementation.  It's a good idea to make all one-argument constructors (other than copy/move) `explicit`, unless we really want them to be converting constructors.

If we include `<numeric>`, we could use `std::iota()` instead of the loop to generate the dummy data (I don't think that's necessarily better, but you should know it exists).  That's helped if we provide `begin()` and `end()` methods:

```
public:
    int *begin() { return mArray.get(); }
    int *end() { return begin() + mSize; }
    int const *begin() const { return mArray.get(); }
    int const *end() const { return begin() + mSize; }
```

```
MyContainer::MyContainer(std::size_t size)
    : mSize(size),
      mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize] : nullptr)
{
    // for testing purpose only
    std::iota(begin(), end(), 0);
}
```

### Copy constructor

This looks good, apart from the missing check to avoid passing a null pointer to `std::copy`; it can also be simplified using the `begin()` and `end()` methods:

```
MyContainer::MyContainer(const MyContainer& other)
    : mSize(other.mSize),
      mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize] : nullptr)
{
    if (mArray) {
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
    }
}
```

### Assignment operators

These are slightly easier to implement if we write a `swap()` as a member, rather than as a class method:

```
MyContainer& MyContainer::swap(MyContainer& other)
{
    using std::swap;
    // Note: no need to check other != this, as self-swap is safe
    swap(mSize, other.mSize);
    swap(mArray, other.mArray);
    return *this;
}
```

It can be a public method, just like the standard containers.

Then the assignments are simply

```
MyContainer& MyContainer::operator=(const MyContainer& other)
{
    MyContainer tmp(other);
    return swap(tmp);
}

MyContainer& MyContainer::operator=(MyContainer&& other) noexcept
{
    return swap(other);
}
```

However, we can combine this into a single method if we *pass-by-value* - at no cost in the number of memory allocations:

```
MyContainer& MyContainer::operator=(MyContainer other) noexcept
{
    return swap(other);
}
```

Although this method is `noexcept` remember that if the compiler needs to copy into `other`, that copy may throw - we maintain strong exception safety even then.

Note also that there's no need to reset before swapping in the new value - we're leaving `other` in a valid state, ready for its destructor.

### Destructor

Don't declare an empty destructor.  If you create a class to be used as a base class, write

```
virtual ~MyContainer() = default;
```

But in this case, it's better to omit the destructor completely.

### Reset method

I don't think this is needed - we can simply assign an empty `MyCollection`.

### Dump method

Prefer to pass `std::ostream` to use, rather than only supporting output to `std::cout`.

Avoid `std::endl` unless you have a real need to flush the stream.

Use an unsigned type for the loop variable (or, use iterators).

---

## Modified code

This has no leaks (tested in Valgrind).  I believe it's still exception-safe, though haven't tested that specifically.

// Declaration

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <memory>

class MyContainer
{
private:
    std::size_t mSize;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> mArray;

public:
    explicit MyContainer(std::size_t size = 0);
    MyContainer(const MyContainer& other);
    MyContainer(MyContainer&& other) noexcept;
    MyContainer& operator=(MyContainer other) noexcept;
    MyContainer& swap(MyContainer& other);
    void dump(std::ostream& os);

    int *begin() { return mArray.get(); }
    int *end() { return begin() + mSize; }
    int const *begin() const { return mArray.get(); }
    int const *end() const { return begin() + mSize; }
};
```

// Implementation

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>
#include <numeric>

MyContainer::MyContainer(std::size_t size)
    : mSize(size),
      mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize] : nullptr)
{
    // canned data for tests - remove for real use
    if (mArray) {
        std::iota(begin(), end(), 0);
    }
}

MyContainer::MyContainer(const MyContainer& other)
    : mSize(other.mSize),
      mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize] : nullptr)
{
    if (mArray) {
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
    }
}

MyContainer::MyContainer(MyContainer&& other) noexcept
    : mSize{0},
      mArray{nullptr}
{
    swap(other);
}

MyContainer& MyContainer::operator=(MyContainer other) noexcept
{
    return swap(other);
}

MyContainer& MyContainer::swap(MyContainer& other)
{
    // Note: no need to check other != this, as self-swap is safe
    std::swap(mSize, other.mSize);
    mArray.swap(other.mArray);
    return *this;
}


void MyContainer::dump(std::ostream& os)
{
    os << "Size: " << mSize << '\n';
    for (auto it = begin();  it != end();  ++it)
        os << ' ' << *it;
    os << '\n';
}
```

// Test

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    MyContainer a{6};
    auto b = a;
    a.dump(std::clog);
    b.dump(std::clog);
    std::clog << '\n';

    MyContainer c;
    c = std::move(a);
    a.dump(std::clog);
    c.dump(std::clog);
}
```

---

## Suggested extensions

- Add a public `size()` and `empty()` methods - once we have `size()`, then `dump()` can be a public non-member function.
- Add a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list<int>`, and one that takes a pair of iterators (the former might delegate to the latter; use `std::distance()` to obtain the required size from iterators).
- Make it generic (i.e. a template class)
- Add the rest of the begin/end methods (`cbegin()`, `cend()`, `crbegin()`, `crend()`, and both const and non-const implementations of `rbegin()` and `rend()`).  Declare the usual names for the iterator types: `iterator`, `const_iterator`, `reverse_iterator`, `const_reverse_iterator`.

Comment: I would also suggest making the constructor explicit. Currently this compiles: `MyContainer a = 7;`, which to me just looks odd. Of course, if you do so, you might want to create a constructor without arguments, which could delegate to `MyContainer(0)`. That way, you can still create e.g. containers containing `MyContainer` (if you don't, `MyContainer` won't be default constructible).

Comment: And yes, it is default-constructible - `explicit` doesn't affect that.

Comment: Ah, learn something new every day :). Makes sense actually, since obviously the container of `MyContainer` objects is only going to want to create `MyContainer` objects.